# Grouping dataframes and getting specific groups

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

What is the best way to group a dataframe and be able to get groups as dataframes by group key? For instance, how to group by date and then get records for specific date?
Basically an equivalent to `get_group` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html) in Pandas.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the groups into a list is what I can think of, example

```
wut=by(iris[,-5],list(iris$Species),colMeans)
wut["setosa"]
$setosa
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.006        3.428        1.462        0.246
```

Comment: I think using `identity` instead of `colMeans` is more appropriate, but otherwise this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @spacemonkey If you are not interested in performing any grouping then yes, I assumed that you wanted to do some grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group_split](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html) in the dplyr package to return a list of data frames separated by a grouping variable

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean))
```